How to send an email if the same data is inserted into PostgreSQL for 1 hour continuously?
I'm developing a backend application using Spring Boot, and my application uses PostgreSQL as the database. Sensor data is being inserted into the database every second.
I want to monitor the data and send an email notification if the same value is inserted into the database continuously for 1 hour. For example:
If the value 42 is inserted into the table every second for 1 hour, I want to detect this and send an email.
Here are my main questions:
Should I implement this logic in my Spring Boot application (e.g., using a scheduled job to query and monitor the data)?
Is it better to handle this entirely within PostgreSQL (e.g., using triggers or other database mechanisms)?
What are the pros and cons of each approach, and which one would you recommend for this use case? If possible, I would appreciate code examples or guidance on how to implement it.

I would probably do something like that:
@Service
public class SensorMonitor {

    @Autowired
    private SensorDataRepository sensorDataRepository;

    
    private Map<String, SensorDataRecord> sensorDataMap;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sensorDataMap = new HashMap<>();
        //todo fill map from db from last hour per sensor when service is restarted
    }

    
    public void insertSensorData(String sensorName, int currentValue) {
            String sensorName = data.getSensorName();
            int currentValue = data.getValue();
            LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now();

            sensorDataRepository.save(...);

            SensorData record = sensorDataMap.get(sensorName);
            if (record == null) {
                record = new SensorData(currentValue, currentTime);
                sensorDataMap.put(sensorName, record);
            } else {
                if (record.getValue() == currentValue) {
                    if (record.getTimestamp().plusHours(1).isBefore(currentTime)) {
                        sendNotification(sensorName, currentValue);
                        sensorDataMap.remove(sensorName);
                    }
                } else {
                    record.setValue(currentValue);
                    record.setTimestamp(currentTime);
                }
            }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String sensorName, int value) {
        //send notification
    }

    private static class SensorData {
        private int value;
        private LocalDateTime timestamp;
        ....

    }
}

To prevent too many database requests i would keep the values in memory.
note:
If you would like to visualize your sensor data grafana might be an option. then you can send the notification/alert from there

Why would you keep the data in memory when the goal is to store it in the database? One check per second is imho next to nothing

it depends of the amount of data that are stored. he probably won't have just 1 sensor.  In my example the data are stored into the db ( sensorDataRepository.save(...);). just the monitoring is done inmemory. but yeah it would also be possible to do the check by a query. something like that: SELECT value FROM sensor_data WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour' GROUP BY value. if only 1 records exists you can send the notification
